# Find Logged User Id

Tags: php, laravel

How can I find the user id from Auth, I have used multiAuth Functionality, when I print this `$userDetails=Auth::user()->get();`

```
    Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser Object
(
    [attributes:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [username] => pradeep -1
            [password] => $2y$10$Qx5wyQEbI7fdBFFl.H3v2.fsm.GiAZ7x72azO7y0Rda350z5TCrGG
            [email] => pradeep33001@gmail.com
            [phone] => 
            [name] => Pradeep Kumar -1
            [created_at] => 2014-03-24 11:50:58
            [updated_at] => 2014-03-24 11:50:58
        )

)
```

No I would like to know how can I find id.

Comment: may be `Auth::user()->id;` or this `Auth::user()->get()->id;`

Comment: A bulletproof way to get id of any Eloquent model is `$model->getKey();` so, based on what @ferozakbar says, maybe `Auth::user()->getKey();` is your best bet? That said, I don't know anything about multiAuth.